# neovim, statusline when vectical split

Tags: neovim, statusline

I have a custom statusline that I build in a function. My function is mainly to perform some string substitutions in the path of the current file.

In `init.vim`

```
let g:mystatus = ''
function! UpdateStatusline()
    let g:mystatus =expand('%:p:~')
    let g:mystatus = substitute(g:mystatus, "foo", "bar", "g")   <--- make a substitution
    set statusline=%{g:mystatus}\ [l=%l]
endfunction

augroup StatuslineUpdate
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter,BufWinEnter * call UpdateStatusline()
augroup END
```

At this point, when I open `/home/daniel/foo.txt`, I see `/home/daniel/bar.txt [l=1]`.
ok.

Now I vertically split my view to open an other file (`:vertical split other.txt`).

I want the left statusline to show `foo.txt` (or `bar.txt` after substitution) and the right statusline to show `other.txt`.

The current behavior is that, when my cursor is on left, both statuslines are show `bar.txt` and when my cursor is on right, both show  `other.txt`.

QUESTION 1: how to modify `autocmd BufEnter,BufWinEnter * call UpdateStatusline()` to only update the statusline on the side I'm going to ?

QUESTION 2: (maybe equivalent to question 1). How to have two independent statuslines ?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to not pass trough an intermediate variable and to directly chain the substitutions.

```
set statusline=%{expand('%:p:~')
                        \->substitute('foo','[bar]','')
                        \->substitute('blabla','[blublu]','')}
                        \ [l=%l]
```